# table sort after new rows added

Tags: javascript, html

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/14ob64og/9/)

Can anyone tell me what to use to trigger initial sort after rows dynamically added to a table on page load?

```
$('.tablesorter2').trigger('update');

var sorting = [[1,0]]; 

$('.tablesorter2').trigger('sorton',sorting);
```

The sorton function is not working to trigger the initial sort on "Age".

Here's the full script:

```
var options = {
        theme: 'default',
        widgets: ['editable'],
        widgetOptions : {
          editable_columns       : [0,1,2],      
          editable_enterToAccept : true,          
          editable_autoAccept    : true,          
          editable_autoResort    : false,         
          editable_validate      : null,         
          editable_noEdit        : 'no-edit',     
          editable_editComplete  : 'editComplete'
       }
}
$('.tablesorter2').tablesorter(options).children('tbody').on('editComplete','td', function(event, config){
    var $this = $(this),
        tr = $this.parent('tr'),
        $allRows = config.$tbodies.children('tr'), 
        tid = tr.data('tid'),
        input="",
        name = $(this).data('name'),
        newContent = $(this).text();
        input = '<input value="'+newContent+'" name="'+name+'[]" type="hidden">';

        $this.find('.j_input').html(input);
    });

$('button').click(function(){
    var item_html = "";
    item_html += '<tr><td>Mary</td><td>5</td><td>Good</td><td>...</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td></tr>';
   $('tbody').append(item_html);
    $('.tablesorter2').trigger('update');
    var sorting = [[1,0]]; 
    $('.tablesorter2').trigger('sorton',sorting);
});
```

HTML:

```
<button>Add</button>
<table class="tablesorter2">
    <thead>
    <tr data-tid='12'>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Conditions</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Del</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-tid='13'>
            <td><div>Peter</div></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-name='age'>18<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-name='conditions'>Good<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-name='notes'>...<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox'/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td data-name='age'>12<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-name='conditions'>Good<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-name='notes'>On medication<span class='j_input'></span></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox'/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$('.tablesorter2').trigger('sorton',[sorting]);
```